# ffmpeg No such filter: 'palettegen' in linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

1.

```
my system 
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2.ffmpeg is download from
http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

3.I had download the `ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz` ,unpackage this file, and run : `./ffmpeg`
then `ffmpeg` has installed. I check it by using : `ffmpeg -version` 
no problems.

I run those command in my system is no problem:

```
cd /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/ffmpeg-3.1.1-64bit-static 

./ffmpeg -y -ss 10 -t 3 -i /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/videos/6.mp4 -vf fps=10,scale=177:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/palettegens/6.png 

./ffmpeg -y -ss 10 -t 3 -i /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/videos/6.mp4 -i /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/palettegens/6.png -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=177:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/6.gif
```

but when I invoke this command in java, errors happend, why?

```
String cmd1 = "/home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/ffmpeg -y -ss 10 -t 3 -i /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/videos/6.mp4 -vf fps=10,scale=177:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/palettegens/6.png";
String cmd2 = "/home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/ffmpeg-3.1.1-64bit-static/ffmpeg -y -ss 10 -t 3 -i /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/videos/6.mp4 -i /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/palettegens/6.png -filter_complex \"fps=10,scale=177:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse\" /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/6.gif";

String result1 = executeCommand(cmd1);
String result2 = executeCommand(cmd2);

private static String executeCommand(String command) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

**errors:**

> result1:
>  result2:ffmpeg version 3.1.1-static
>   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg
>   developers
>    built with gcc 5.4.0 (Debian 5.4.0-4) 20160609
>  
>   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static
>   --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --enable-libvidstab --enable-libsoxr --enable-frei0r --enable-libfribidi --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --enable-librtmp --enable-libmfx --enable-libzimg --cc=gcc 
>    libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100 
>    libavcodec     57.
>   48.101 / 57. 48.101 
>    libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100 
>    libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101 
>    libavfilter
>   6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100 
>    libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100 
>    libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100 
>    libpostproc
>   54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 
>  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/videos/6.mp4': 
>    Metadata:
>   
>       major_brand     : isom 
>       minor_version   : 512 
>       compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41 
>       encoder         : Lavf56.40.101 
>    Duration: 00:04:36.64, start: -3.338000, bitrate: 1089 kb/s 
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360, 997 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 16k tbn, 30 tbc (default) 
>       Metadata: 
>         handler_name    : VideoHandler 
>       Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (Main) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 88 kb/s (default) 
>       Metadata: 
>         handler_name    : SoundHandler 
>  Input #1, png_pipe, from '/home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/palettegens/6.png':
>   
>    Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A 
>       Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 16x16 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc 
>  [AVFilterGraph @ 0x45c5260] No such filter:
>   '"fps' 
>  Error initializing complex filters. 
>  Invalid
>   argument

Comment: the cmd1 is execute success, but cmd2 is not, anyone who can help? thanks very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: @manetsus  Thank you for your valuable advice,  the next time will pay attention to

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with your FFmpeg binary, this is almost certainly related to escaping characters in the shell environment that the commands run in.

Examine the error message:

```
No such filter: '"fps'
```

FFmpeg thinks the filter being called is `"fps`.

Try removing the quotes around filter_complex i.e.

```
-filter_complex fps=10,scale=177:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse
```

Or if that doesn't work, enclose it in single quotes.

```
-filter_complex 'fps=10,scale=177:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse'
```

Comment: thank you Mulvya, I tried these two ways, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I got this cos of copying a cmd had put curly quotes into the command somehow. evil!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wrote a shell: gifcreate.sh, I use java to call it, it's works well.

## this is myshell

```
#/bin/bash

_srcFile=$1     #video file path
_descFile=$2    #output GIF file
_width=$3       #widht of output GIF file
_start=$4       #skip the first $_start seconds of the $_srcFile
_time=$5        #create a $_time second output
_cover=$6       #overwrite the palette and gif if exist, y is yes,n is not
_fps=$7         #Frame rate,can control GIF definition,
_palettegenFile=$8  #palette file path

cd /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/ffmpeg-3.1.1-64bit-static
./ffmpeg -$6 -t $_time -i $_srcFile -vf fps=$_fps,scale=$_width:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen $_palettegenFile
./ffmpeg -$6 -t $_time -i $_srcFile -i $_palettegenFile -filter_complex "fps=$_fps,scale=$_width:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" $_descFile
```

## this is my calling method in shell

```
/home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gifcreate.sh /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/videos/6.mp4 /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/1469694815605_8898.gif 177 0 3 y 5 /home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gif_images/palettegens/1469694815605_8898.png
```

## this is my calling method in java

```
String cmd1 = "/home/web/tomcat-6.0.29/zhouletest/gifcreate.sh "+srcFile+" "+descFile+" "+width+" "+start+" "+time+" "+(cover?"y":"n")+" "+fps+" "+palettegenFile;

Runtime r1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
    final Process process1 = r1.exec(cmd1);
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                process1.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("createScaleGifFromVideo thread error:", e);
            }
        }
    });
    thread1.start();
    thread1.join(5000);//wait for the child thread up to 5 second
    if(thread1.isAlive()){
        process1.destroy();
        log.error("createScaleGifFromVideo: gif create is not ended, because it's cost more then 5s.");
    }
```

## Reference

https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen when you're using a separate language or system to generate your `ffmpeg` command line call, and if you have a recent-*ish* ffmpeg (that's greater than 3.0) then `palettegen` should be compiled into it, by default.

In my case, after a whole day of experimenting with the command line, it turned out that I needed to escape the `,` in my CLI call that I was generating, with a `\` before it. Due to this, ffmpeg was unable to read the arguments properly, and ended up thinking that I was asking to use 'fps' as a filter, or similar.